# Serializing a treenode like data structure

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm struggling a little with my attempt to serialize the data used in my treeview, we use this as a form of caching data.

Basically i have data such as follows

- PhotoGroup A

  - PhotoGroup B

    - PhotoGroup F
  - PhotoGroup C
- PhotoGroup D
- PhotoGroup E

As you (hopefully) can see, i have objects called photogroup, that can contain zero or more photogroup's as children, and those children can also contain zero or more photogroups as children.

What i'm wanting to do, is serialize this data into a file, and load it back with all the groups and subgroups. Previously I've flattened the entire structure and relied on a property called ParentGroupID. However that causes problems itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can serialize it into xml or json, and store it into the file. All the mechanisms to serialize/deserialize already exist's and all you need it's just use them. If you have some recursive property disable it's serialization  from one way but leave it in other. I hope you understand an Idea. If you want an answer, please give for us some code samples

Comment: My problem is how to serialize recursively, I need to save the root plus it's children, and their children and their children and so on, I've been unable to find any examples from my searches so i turned to here, What code samples would you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
I hope it will be an answer on your question [PUSH](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PIk8Yu)

And here is the code

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    serializer.Serialize(sw, _class);

    sw.Flush();

    ms.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(myStr);
}
```